# Json file contains 2 id column and an id column returning null value

Tags: asp.net-core

I am reading the data from an external link which returns data  in json format.

I am  calling json in my application. thing working fine except one column returning a null value.

Json file contains 2 id columns one is in Uppercase another one is in capitalization.

I am facing an issue in  the capitalization id column.

```
Json File 


"Values": [
{
  "Id": {
    "label": "internal id",
    "value": "1234"
  },
  "ClassID": {
    "label": "ClassID",
    "value": "39"
  },

  "InternalID": {
    "label": "Internal ID",
    "value": "1794"
  },
   
  "ID": {
    "label": "ID",
    "value": "39"
  },
  "Name": {
    "label": "Name",
    "value": "National school"
  }
```

]

Controller Level

```
 public ActionResult ImportJsonClassData(ClassData classData)
    {
        try
        {
            //action to insert into table
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //  ex.Message  
        }
```

property
ClassData.cs

```
   [JsonProperty("Id")]
    public JsonValue InsertId { get; set; }
   

    [JsonProperty("ClassID")]
    public JsonValue ClassID { get; set; }

    
    [JsonProperty("InternalID")]
    public JsonValue  InternalId { get; set; }
    
         
    [JsonProperty("ID")]
    public JsonValue ID {  get; set;  }

    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    public JsonValue Name { get; set; }
```

Comment: What issue you are facing for that? Additionally please share your backed code how you are managing currently.

Comment: Hi Mid ,
I am try to read the data in controller level ,
please look into my code.

Comment: Yes seen the code but it doesn't tell us what problem your are having with, but suggestion is parse your json then execute your database operation then return if required.

Comment: Would this help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-character-casing ? Maybe 
 the property PropertyNameCaseInsensitive is set to "true"

Comment: Hi ,
Can we add  PropertyNameCaseInsensitive is set to "true" in property class level, concern is due to these changes there shouldn't be any impact to other API.

Comment: Did you tried to handle this with `dynamic` data type?

Comment: I have fixed the issue. Thank you for your suggestion,